# Wrap in quotes all fields of an object with VIM substitute command

Tags: regex, vim, regex-lookarounds

I want to convert

```
{
  foo:"bar",
  hello:"world",
}
```

into

```
{
  "foo":"bar",
  "hello":"world",
}
```

I'm thinking about a substitute commande like this

```
s/(.*):/"<the_thing_captured_on_the_left>"/g
```

But how do I access the content before `:` to wrap it in quotes ?

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
:%s/\w\+:\@=/"&"/
```

where `\@=` applies to the token before it (in this case `:`) and means "if `:` matches, match with zero width just before it (`:help /zero-width`).

And all the rest should be clear given the background you demonstrate.

Equivalently, you can do

```
:%s/\w\+\ze:/"&"/
```

where `\ze` means "match the stuff after this, but don't consume it".

Comment: You could get the same result without the `\%(\)`.

Comment: I think I had wrote it with my mind thinking I should apply a quantifier or something to _it_, but then it turned I had to appy `\@=` to just `:`, and I didn't realize I could remove the grouping. Thanks for pointing that out.